# DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration in azure worker role

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-worker-roles

I have a class which derives from DbConfiguration for executing any Connection Resiliency strategies.

I call it in a web role in Application_Start in global.asax.cs.

Where do I call the same in case of a worker role?

Answer (score 0):

in the app.config of your app (mine is named "WebJob") where you have the tag --EntityFramework-- ... add codeConfigurationType like this:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="WebJob.EFConfigDB, WebJob">
... your EF config here ...
</entityFramework>
```

EFConfigDB is the class i have derived from DbConfiguration. so codeConfigurationType is basically formatted like this which depends on your project:

```
codeConfigurationType="<MyNameSpace>.<Derived DBConfiguration class>, <MyAssembly>"
```

Once you have those above correctly, your DBConfiguration-derived class' parameter-less constructor will be called automatically.